# Getting latitude and longitude from latlng object in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get latitude and longitude on the Googlemap v2.. I have set the onclick listener for mapragment object using the code

```
 map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latln) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String s=latln.toString();

        Log.w("dsfdsf",""+s);

    }
});
```

It provides be the latitude and longitude coordinates in the format lat/lng: (xx.xxxxxx,yy.yyyyy)
I need the exact method to get latitude and longitude data.. I dont want to parse the data using split and get the coordinates..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can easily be found in the [Google Maps API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng):

> **public final class LatLng**
>
> *public final double latitude*
>
> Latitude, in degrees. This value is in the range [-90, 90].
>
> *public final double longitude*
>
> Longitude, in degrees. This value is in the range [-180, 180).

So in your example you should call:

```
double lat = latlng.latitude;
double lng = latlng.longitude;
```

Comment: looks like lot of googlers coming here on how to get latitude/longitude from latlng object in google maps V3, the answer is **use the .lat() and .lng() methods** example: `var mylat = LatLngObject.lat(); var mylng = LatLngObject.lng();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = results1[key][key1].toString().split("(");
console.log(" latlong::"+res);
var res2= res[1].split(",");
console.log(" latlong::"+res2);
latlongFrom[0]=res2[0];
console.log(" latlong::"+latlongFrom[0]);
var res3=res2[1].split(")");
console.log(" latlong::"+res3[0]);
latlongFrom[1]=res3[0];
console.log(" latlong::"+latlongFrom[1]);
```

This is what I have done.
The res contains the value of (lat,long).

Answer (score 0):

To get Latitude and Longitude your have to declare 2  double variables.

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latln) {
        double latitude, longitude;
        latitude(latln.latitude);
        longitude(latln.longitude);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer version please use:

```
double lat = latlng.lat;
double lng = latlng.lng;
```

as `latlng.latitude` and `latlng.longitude` or `latlng.lat()` and `latlng.lng()` will give compilation error.

Comment: Hi user1267449, can you please, if possible, provide a link to any documentation that supports your answer? You can modify and improve your answer by clicking on the **[edit]** link under the post. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the sample JSON and XML responses from the official docs: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses
It clearly shows the response as _lat_ and _lng_

Comment: That's the raw JSON response, not the LatLng class that is used in Android as mentioned in the question asked. Please see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#field-summary

Answer (score -1):

This is for Android solution

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng latln) {
    String s = latln.toString();
    String[] latLng = s.substring(10, s.length() - 1).split(",");
    String sLat = latLng[0];
    String sLng = latLng[1];
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Latitude is: "+sLat+", Longtitude is: "+sLng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Why convert to string only to parse again? Why play with string length instead of splitting with comma?